# In Docker not able to register a third party DLL using regsvr32 [On Windows]

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using Windows 10 Pro.

My Docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/iis
SHELL ["powershell","-command"]

RUN New-Item -Path $env:systemdrive\inetpub\XpServerDllFiles -Type Directory
COPY ./BeastClientPlugIn.dll /inetpub/XpServerDllFiles
RUN Start-Process C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe C:/inetpub/XpServerDllFiles/BeastClientPlugIn.dll

EXPOSE 4849
```

Answer (score -2):

```
regsvr32 /S
```

The /S makes it graphically silent, and allows the registration to complete.

Have fun!

Comment: I have the same issue, the application where the dll belongs was created for x86 should I register the dll in x86 as well ?